# JRebel eclipse older versions, not versions in the update-site

Tags: jrebel

If you paste http://update.zeroturnaround.com/update-site/ into your RAD 8 plugin installer you will only see the latest version, it is not working as well, and is not good for maintenance if we need to enforce a certain version to be sure that things always works a certain way.

How can I get the older versions of a plugin/jrebel plugin??

No info on site...

Answer (score 0):

To get older versions of JRebel itself, you can download the [ZIP archive from the site](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/prev-releases/) and configure the plugin to point to the jrebel.jar from the archive.

Could you please explain, why do you need to **enforce** the certain version?

Comment: Yes, I know, but that is not related to the plugin, i need a previous plugin version, not the jar. In a perfect world, new versions and updates will always work, however, sometimes they don't, as is the case now. If you know a certain version does work, and a new developer comes into a team, do you want to risk getting into issues? You have tested a certain version, it should be my right to decide whether to upgrade or not, and please make it simple. The idea of always enforcing stuff on people is not healthy. Option is the key.

Comment: I should also say, if everyone in a team is to run the same developer environment, then it is critical to be able to pick your plugin version as well.

Comment: I see. in any case, there's no solution right now, but eventually we will host the old versions of eclipse plugin also. This is in plans

Comment: thanks for recognizing that this is a legitimate concern. jRebel have been out for quite some time. Isn't there a dropin that I can download ( special link ) ?

Comment: At the update site page (http://zeroturnaround.com/update-site/) there's a link to update-site.zip that you can download, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: My question is clear, I want to install an older version of the eclipse plugin? How? Is it possible, that zip file is only for the latest plugin version, right?

Comment: Currently, it is only possible to install the latest version of the plugin. No old versions of the plugins are published atm.

Comment: Any news on this front sir ? We are still waiting for putting a version on our chosen plugin. Thanks

Comment: The archives will now be available here: http://update.zeroturnaround.com/update-site-archive/ Is there any particular version you're interested in?